# How do I make an Observer pattern with 2 Swift protocols, where the two associatedtypes must be the same?

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

I'm trying to use [SE-0142 (Associated Type Constraints)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md) to make an Observer pattern with 2 protocols, `IsObserver` (like a client) and `HasObservers` (like a server), where there's a shared `DataType` that represents the type of the thing being observed.

I need objects conforming to  `HasObservers` to be capable of being a struct or a class, and I want the `IsObserver` to be intentionally limited to be a class (want, but do not need).

I'm not good with generics... after several hours I got this far, with the compiler error in a comment inline below. I'm stuck and not sure where to go next, and I'm not sure this approach is even possible or reasonable. All help much appreciated!

```swift
import Foundation

protocol IsObserver: class {
    associatedtype DataType
    func dataDidUpdate(_ data: [DataType])
}

struct Observation<T: IsObserver> {
    weak var observer: T?
}


protocol HasObservers {
    associatedtype DataType : IsObserver where DataType.DataType == DataType
    static var observations: [ObjectIdentifier : Observation<IsObserver>] { get set } // ERROR: "Value of protocol type 'IsObserver' cannot conform to 'IsObserver'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols"
    static func tellObserversDataDidUpdate(_ data: [DataType])
}

extension HasObservers {
    static func tellObserversDataDidUpdate(_ data: [DataType]) {
        for (id, observation) in observations {
            guard let observer = observation.observer else {
                observations.removeValue(forKey: id)
                continue
            }
            observer.dataDidUpdate(data)
        }
    }

    static func addObserver<T: IsObserver>(_ observer: T) {
        let id = ObjectIdentifier(observer)
        let ob = Observation.init(observer: observer)
        observations[id] = ob
    }

    static func removeObserver<T: IsObserver>(_ observer: T) {
        let id = ObjectIdentifier(observer)
        observations.removeValue(forKey: id)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Alright, got there in the end. Was harder than I thought and required type erasure. In this gist there are two versions: the first one is the one with associatedtype protocols per the original question. It is limited though - the object that is the observer can only observe one type. So I made another variant that can have multiple types but doesn't use associatetype protocols so the observer has to check the type manually.

https://gist.github.com/xaphod/4f8a6402429759b6b3fd8ea2d8ea53c4

Comment: @Jessy that’s short-sighted: most of us have professional apps to support, which of course must support all the way back to iOS 9 in some cases. Also, isn’t Combine specific to Apple? What if I want to do this on the server?

Comment: @Jessy umm you might be a hobbyist but some of us do this for a living. Support for iOS12 is not optional in the pro realm

Comment: @xaphod what's the use of observation vs observer? maybe I'm not following

Comment: @NewDev I'm not sure I understand your question, do you mean why does `struct Observation` exist? It's because I want to have a weak memory ref on the observer, in case it is a class that needs to deinit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll simplify your use case a bit (ignore observations) to hopefully get the concept across.

`HasObservers` basically has 2 associated types - the `DataType` and the `IsObserver` type, and then you'd constrain the `IsObserver` type to have the right `DataType`

```
protocol IsObserver {
  associatedtype DataType
  func dataDidUpdate(_ data: [DataType])
}

protocol HasObservers {
  associatedtype DataType
  associatedtype ObserverType: IsObserver where ObserverType.DataType == DataType

  static func addObserver(_ observer: ObserverType)
  static func tellObserversDataDidUpdate(_ data: [DataType])

  // ..
}
```

Comment: This does help get me further (thanks!), but, having the extra associatedtype appears to mean that the struct/class conforming to `HasObservers` has to know up front what type its Observer is going to be. Which I don't want. For example: how do you declare the var that holds the observers in the HasObserver, with this approach?

Comment: @xaphod - I see, so yeah - this works when you have a specific implementation of an observer for each `DataType` (e.g. `HasStringObservers` and `StringObserver`). If you have different implementations of IsObserver for a given data type (e.g. `StringObserverA` and `StringObserverB`), then you'd need to use a type erasure pattern. You can read more about it here: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/different-flavors-of-type-erasure-in-swift/

Comment: Type erasure was a lot harder but I got there in the end. I'm updating my question above with the link to a gist